# Is there a way to override the X button that closes an app?

Tags: android

I'm basically looking to override the function that is called when a user closes an app with the 'X' button so I can tell the app to run its shutdown function, which deletes memory (using C++) and saves data. Something like onDestroy(), which unfortunately isn't called when a user closes an app this way.

Comment: Can you clarify why X button you're talking about? I see nothing like this in any of the apps I use.

Comment: When the app is minimized (when the squared button is pushed) an 'x' appears in the top right corner of the app, which allows the user to close the app.  I'm not sure if 'minimized' is the correct term for this on Android, though.

Answer (score 0):

On any form of shutdown, onDestroy should be called.. can you post your source? The only reason I can think it wouldn't run is if your app crashes and throws and error on this type of close. ([Activity lifecycle reference](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png))

EDIT: Maybe see if onStop gives you any luck?